# "unterminated address regex" using variable in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use a variable in a sed append and hitting an issue.

The following command works as expected:

```
sed -i "\:#file = /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1495965866386_0001/container_1495965866386_0001_01_000002/stderr:a file = /path/to/other/file" /etc/conf/service.conf
```

However if I replace the pattern with a variable I'm hitting an error:

```
$ echo $item
#file = /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1495965866386_0001/container_1495965866386_0001_01_000002/stdout

$ sed -i "\:$item:a file = /path/to/other/file" /etc/conf/service.conf
sed: -e expression #1, char 122: unterminated address regex
```

EDIT for more info: So the 'item' variable is being populated from an array. That array is created from a readarray and grep:

```
$readarray LINES < <(grep "#file = /mnt/var/" /etc/conf/service.conf)
$item=${LINES[1]}

$echo $item
#file = /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1495965866386_0001/container_1495965866386_0001_01_000002/stdout
```

However I've found if i populate 'item' manually it then works e.g:

```
$item="#file = /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1495965866386_0001/container_1495965866386_0001_01_000002/stdout"
$sed -i "\:$item:a file = /path/to/other/file" /etc/conf/service.conf
$
```

So something strange seems to be happening with the readarray/grep

Comment: It works for me just fine.

Comment: Worked fine for me, too.

Comment: Does it start working if you remove `-i`, or change it to `-i.bak`?

Comment: Nope, no change

Comment: Updated with more info

Comment: First change `echo $item` to `echo "$item"` so it's quoted sensibly and then see if there's a trailing control character or something by `echo "$item" | cat -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here turned out to be newline characters that were being pulled in as part of the grep.
This is why populating $item manually worked - no '\n'

Thanks to Ed Morton for pointing me in the right direction. While

```
echo "$item" | cat -v
```

did not show anything I added '-t' to the readarray command to trim newline characters:

```
$readarray -t LINES < <(grep "#file = /mnt/var/" /etc/conf/service.conf)
```

After that things worked as expected.